# How to extract variable from http_get response

Tags: php, web-services, curl, http-get

I have successfully completed an HTTP GET request using PHP and cURL. How do I extract a variable from the response?

Here is the response I am receiving:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://ws.example.com/resumes/">
  <Packet>
    <Errors />
    <SessionToken>1234567890</SessionToken>
  </Packet>
</string>
```

I need to extract the "1234567890" and set it as a PHP the $sessionid variable.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). It will be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $xml->Packet->SessionToken;
```